# Node hangs while listening

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a Node server which is getting data - (a few of integers) from a webpage - once it receives the data, I'd like it to process the data, while still listening for updates on new data received.
My problem is that the server code appears to sit waiting for data to arrive - so it's kind of hung up.
Here is a clip of my node server code.  The wait seems to be right around the socket.on line.
Is there anything that can be done to allow other tasks to be done while still listening for new data to be received?

```
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server); //require socket.io module and pass the
  var path = require('path');
  var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio, //include pigpio to interact with the GPIO
  ledRed = new Gpio(4, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}), //use GPIO pin 4 as output for RED
  ledGreen = new Gpio(17, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}), //use GPIO pin 17 as output for
  ledBlue = new Gpio(27, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}), //use GPIO pin 27 as output for B
  anglev = 0, //set starting value of RED variable to off (0 for common cathode)
  speedv = 0.0, //set starting value of GREEN variable to off (0 for common cath
  dirv = 0, //set starting value of BLUE variable to off (0 for common cathode)
  stopv = 0, // if this is set to 1 then stop the turntable at preset stopping p
  refv = 1,// if this is set to 1 then log the info when the turntable goes by r
  newspeed = 0; //this is the conversion of the speed from 0-6 to 0-255 for pwm

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
});

  server.listen(8080);

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('rgbLed', function(data) { //get light switch status from client -
               console.log(data); //output data from WebSocket connection to con
               anglev=parseInt(data.angle);
               speedv=parseFloat(data.speed);
               dirv=parseInt(data.direction);
               stopv=parseInt(data.stop);
               refv=parseInt(data.refv);
               newspeed = Math.round(speedv * 42.5);
               ledRed.pwmWrite(newspeed); //setspeed
    });
});
```